# One Active Directory for two offices

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have two offices that are connected over a site-2-site VPN. On the main office I have Windows 2008 AD+DNS. The branch office has, since before, it's own Windows 2000 AD+DNS.

Can I move the AD and DNS services from the branch office to the main office without affecting continuity?

Comment: Maybe it's usefull to know the bandwidth between the offices

Comment: We have 100mb site to site. So bandwidth should not be an issue. I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Without affecting continuity 
>   In one word: No!

In more words, not without substantial preparation and maintenance window.

I would:

- Create a 2008 domain controller replica in the branch site and ensure it can update from primary site
- Document or define group policies in use on the 2000 domain and define equivalents in 2008
- Add a single PC or one per significant group, test group policy, network shares, migrated profiles (friendly user guinea pigs are invaluable)
- Create all the users in 2008, identify any issues with a partial set of users migrated. This will give you an idea of whether you can have a maintenance window or windows.
- Schedule users in batches if you can. Then on the weekend, remove their machines from the old domain and add them to the new one. Migrate current profile (roaming i hope)

This is based on a small manageable user base and adequate hands on resources to complete. I've heard of tools that do a lot of donkey work for you, but i'm excluding them as A i haven't used them & B. likely cost sizeable bucks.

M.

Comment: You can use ADMT instead of creating new users/computer accounts by hand, this will migrate profiles, translate group membership and change permissions on any file\print servers that are migrated as well. You *can* do this with very minimal interruption to continuity. Other than that, the rest is a decent answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. 
It looks easier than I thought at first.